# access cookie in _Layout.cshtml in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core

I'm trying to store an authentication-key into my cookies when login succeeded:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Bearer", accessToken, cookieMonsterOptions);
```

So in the controller-class this works. I can easily create and read my cookies. 
But now I want to check and, if it exists, read the value of a cookie in my `_Layout.cshtml` and show the name of the logged in user - or the link to login.
But how can I read my cookies in the partial `_Layout.cshtml`?

```
string value = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("Bearer");
```

doesn't work. It tries to add either `System.Web` to my usings or says HttpContext is static and needs a reference to access `Request`.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Just a suggest: Instead of accessing cookie in `_Layout.cshtml`, i would use view component to handle your case. You can create a view component and pass cookie value as model property.

Comment: wow, that's nice. didn't work with view components for now. thanks. You want to add an answere with an example here? ;)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core there is no concept of a static HttpContext any more. Dependency Injection rules in the new Microsoft Web Framework. Regarding views there is the `@inject` directive for accessing registered services like `IHttpContextAccessor` service (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/dependency-injection.html).

Using the `IHttpContextAccessor` you can get the `HttpContext` and the cookie information like in this example.

```
 @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

 @{
    foreach (var cookie in HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
    {
        @cookie.Key  @cookie.Value
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, finally I came to the same result :) but here, have my "accept" - this works :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger - thanks - we were working simultaniously; happy coding.

Answer (score 16):

So I found the solution, if anyone needs it, too:

Add into `ConfigureServices` the service for `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

into your `_Layout.cs` inject `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextaccessor
```

access the cookies with

```
@Html.Raw(httpContextaccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Bearer"])
```

Answer (score 12):

You don't need  Dependency Injection or anything else. You access cookie on *ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC* in view like that:

```
@{
Context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("Bearer", out string value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was lost looking for Request under controllerbase forgetting it was context. A simple Context.Request.Cookies.Any(x=>x.Key=="NewTempUser") was enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to handle your case: using view component.

Here is a simple example for your case:

`LoggedInComponent.cs`:

```
public class LoggedInComponent: ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return View(HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("Bearer"));
    }
}
```

Component View:

```
@model string

@Html.Raw(Model)
```

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("LoggedInComponent")
```

Also see https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html

**Edit for directly access cookie**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

@Context.Request.Cookies.Get("Bearer")
```

See [How to access session from a view in ASP .NET Core MVC 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240696/how-to-access-session-from-a-view-in-asp-net-core-mvc-1-0)

Answer (score 2):

**CookieManager** wrapper allows you to read/write/update/delete http cookie in asp.net core. it has fluent API's to ease of use.

Try my nuget packge: https://github.com/nemi-chand/CookieManager

It has two interface ICookie and ICookieManager which helps you to play with http cookie in asp.net core

just add the CookieManager in configure service in start up class

```
//add CookieManager
services.AddCookieManager();
```

In Layout page inject the Cookie Manager

```
@inject CookieManager.ICookie _httpCookie

_httpCookie.Get("Bearer")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this for about 2 hours as none of these methods work for me in .NET Core 2.2 to read a cookie value in _Layout.cshtml resulting in either a blank value or an error.
I have a cookie set that stores the name of the database the user is connected to and I want to show this in the footer of the web application (i.e. Training or Live).

What did work was to add the following to the top of _Layout.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
```

Then I added this at the location where I wanted the value of the cookie to appear:

```
@if (@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("SystemDatabase", out string SystemDatabase))
{
  @SystemDatabase @:System
}
else
{
  @:Live System
}
```

This now prints either "Live System" or "Training System".
No changes to Startup.cs were required.

Comment: Thats basically the same thing, that Ralf Bönning does. Only thing is, you are accessing a specific value by key, and Ralf iterates through all keys.

Comment: Yes it is similar but in the _Layout.cshtml page this doesn't work for me and produces an error `string value = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("Bearer");` whereas this does work `@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("SystemDatabase", out string SystemDatabase)` and with the try bit I think it would fail gracefully rather than show an unhandled exception if not found.