# C# ASP.NET Core MVC An object reference is required

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to access session from the `.cshtml` page:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
...
<div>
     @HttpContext.Session.GetString("role");

</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController: Controller
{
     public IActionResult UserLogin(DVAAccount user)
     {
         ....
       
         HttpContext.Session.SetString("role", user.UserRole);

         return View("Index");
     }
}
```

However I can't seem to retrieve the session in the front-end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access session from a view in ASP .NET Core MVC 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240696/how-to-access-session-from-a-view-in-asp-net-core-mvc-1-0)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it does not

Comment: So what is the problem. Does exception occur? Or you just have blank space instead of actual value on the page?

Comment: @Alexander I got An object reference is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mvc usually doesnt use session, so you need to add some code to your startup to use it

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});


.....

//app.UseRouting();

//app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();
```

if  you use Net 6+ you have to use builder.Services instead of services